# Getting an error using SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, connection-string

```
public void DataGrid_Data()
{
    // 2 second delay before loading DataGrid
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();

            // Attempt to connect to SQL Server database and populate DataGrid with database tables. 
            try
            {
                string connectionString = (@"Data Source=ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT `hb_disputes`.`DSP_ID`, `hb_disputes`.`ACCOUNT`, `hb_disputes`.`CUST_NAME`,`hb_disputes`.`PREM_ADDR`, `hb_status`.`Status`, `hb_disputes`.`OPENED`, `hb_disputes`.`DEADLINE`, `hb_rpttype`.`ReportType`, `hb_ratetype`.`Rate Type`FROM `hb_disputes` LEFT JOIN `hb_status` ON `hb_disputes`.`STATUS` = `hb_status`.`STSID` LEFT JOIN `hb_rpttype` ON `hb_disputes`.`RPTTYPE` = `hb_rpttype`.`RPTID` LEFT JOIN `hb_ratetype` ON `hb_disputes`.`REV_CLS` = `hb_ratetype`.`RTID`; ", connection);
                connection.Open();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                connection.Close();

                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection is not available at this time. Please contact your database administrator ");
            }
        };
}
```

I've been using MYSQL for my application and I decided to switch to SQL Server. I rebuilt the database in SQL Server and connected it to Visual Studio, which provided me my connection string. However, since there is a "\" between the computer name and `SQLEXPRESS` I am getting an

> Unrecognized escape sequence

error. I've tried using "@" and "\" but I am still not able to connect to the database. I also just simply replaced my `MySqlCommand` with `SqlCommand`.

Comment: You've followed the clues correctly and made proper changes so far. Kudos for that. What's the exception you're getting? Your `catch` block needs an exception type in order to inspect the exception; blindly catching like that is not a good idea. Also, while MySQL uses backticks to quote names, SQL Server uses square brackets (or double quotes if you have `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` on), so you'll need to modify your query accordingly before it'll be ready to execute the query.

Comment: My SQL statement needed to change I needed to use [ ]  instead of ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this

```
   string connectionString = (@"Data Source=ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
```

To

```
   string connectionString = ("Data Source=ComputerName\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
```

Let me know if it helps

2 backslashes

Comment: That won't change anything. It's just a different way of using a backslash in a string. It's still a backslash.

Comment: Correction: you have 3 backslashes, which means that `\S` will give the same "Unrecognized escape sequence" error message.

Comment: Damm I see it 2 must be an issue in my mobile that's why I added 3 it looked 1 when I answered initially

Comment: That's better, but now refer to my first comment.

Comment: I have to confirm this. I am pretty sure it worked in one of the project let me grab computer in sometime I'll attach image with it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/U0x2Wn7

See with double slashes code passed :)

Comment: My point was not that you were wrong about it working, but rather that doing it that way, or with one backslash and the `@` prefix, is no different and pointless as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site...  From my C#/SQL-Server work, My connection string is different such as

```
Server=myServerName\theInstanceName; Database=myDataBase; Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

as compared to your

```
Data Source=ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;
```

Not sure if that is what the problem is for your connection.